# Is the expression "a su frente" a valid substitute for "frente a ti"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

In the phrase below, can the expression "a su frente" be used instead of "frente a ti"?

Does it make any sense in Spanish?

> Aquí estoy yo otra vez **frente a ti** pidiendo perdón.
>
> Aqui estoy yo otra vez **a su frente** pidiendo perdón.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two comments. You are mixing the formal you with the informal you so they cannot be exact equivalents even if they ae both right. You do not need to put _yo_ as the listener can work that out from _estoy_ unless you want to emphasise _yo_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression "frente a" is what we call a "locución preposicional" (something like an extended preposition) and, even if "frente" can be a noun meaning "front" or "facade" (masculine in Spanish) or "forehead" (feminine in Spanish), it does not work like a similar *locución preposicional* which contains a noun that can be accompanied by an article or a possessive.

Thus, while we can say:

- Aquí estoy al lado de usted. (to your side, next to you, beside you)
- Aquí estoy a su lado.
- Aquí estoy a tu lado.

("costado" is a less usual alternative having the same meaning as "lado")

we have to say:

- Aquí estoy frente a usted. (in front of you)
- Aquí estoy frente a ti.
- Aquí estoy frente a vos. (In countries where "vos" is used)

You might be confused with Portuguese, where people say *na tua/sua frente*.

There is a tendency with other *locuciones preposicionales* to use the possessive, but this is grammatically wrong. With the case of "frente a", nobody will use the possessive. With these *locuciones preposicionales*, many speakers incorrectly use the possessive instead of the grammatical "de XXX":

- *Aquí estoy atrás/detrás suyo/tuyo (wrong for: Aquí estoy detrás de usted/ti/vos) (behind you)
- *Aquí estoy (a)delante suyo/tuyo (wrong for: Aquí estoy delante de usted/ti/vos) (ahead of you)
- *Aquí estoy arriba suyo/tuyo (wrong for: Aquí estoy arriba de usted/ti/vos) (above you)
- *Aquí estoy abajo suyo/tuyo (wrong for: Aquí estoy abajo de usted/ti/vos) (below you)

Comment: Amazing. A million thanks for such a detailed answer. And to think that many, perhaps most, brazilians, including myself until recently, believes that just because we speak Portuguese we can easily learn Spanish whenever we need or decide to. Not so easy at all.

Answer (score 1):

To me the second sentence does not sound correct. Alternatively, you could say

> Aquí estoy yo otra vez frente a usted pidiendo perdón